# Acronymns in plural and full length in latex, after the first instance of using it in the text

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, thesis

With each new chapter of my thesis I need to redefine most acronyms.

I can use `\glsfirst{bmi}` to print "body mass index (BMI)" in my compiled file.

When I want the plural I use `\glspl{bmi}` to get "BMIs" in my compiled file.

How do I get the **full definition** of the acronym in my text in **plural** form, **when I have previously used the acronym**?
i.e. in this example how do I combine `\glsfirst{}` and `\glspl{}` to get "body mass indexes (BMIs)" when I have already used the BMI acronym earlier in the text?

Does a command for this exist, or do I need to just manually type it, and not use `\gls{}`?

(I will tick the correct answer, but I cannot upvote as I don't have enough badges)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\acrfullpl` will produce the full plural form

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries} 

\newacronym{cd}{CD}{compact disc}

\begin{document}
\gls{cd}
\gls{cd}
\acrfullpl{cd}
\end{document}
```

> compact disc (CD)
>
> CD
>
> compact discs (CDs)

However, if there's a clear barrier after which you want to return to a first appearance, you probably want `\glsreset` or `\glsresetall`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries} 

\newacronym{cd}{CD}{compact disc}
\newacronym{dc}{DC}{disc compact}

\begin{document}
\gls{cd} \gls{dc}
\glsresetall[acronym]

\gls{cd} \gls{dc}
\glsreset{cd}

\gls{cd} \gls{dc}
\end{document}
```

> compact disc (CD) disc compact (DC)
>
> compact disc (CD) disc compact (DC)
>
> compact disc (CD) DC

Comment: In [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) you can set an automatic reset at `\section`-type commands, but I can't see an equivalent option in [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `\Glspl` should work just fine:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{bmi}{BMI}{Body Mass Index}

\begin{document}
\section{The Body Mass Index}
Different people do, in fact, have different \Glspl{bmi}. Not many know that! \par
\section{Measurement of the Body Mass Index}
Body Mass Indexes (\Glspl{bmi}) can be measured by the following equasion:

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

[image: Code Example]

Comment: Thanks, but this only works in the first instance of using the acronym. I need the acronym in its full form in plural when it has previously been used in the text. I edited my question to make this clearer.

Comment: I've updated the answer, the solution provided might not be the most elegant, but it certainly works. Also, I suggest you don't use \Glspl for a word like 'index', as you can't form the plural by simply adding a -s to it ;)

Comment: @nerdyllama there's an interface to specify arbitrary plural forms, appending an `s` is just the default.